# How to get the ID of texfield when the value changes?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement an autosuggest functionality in the program I am making where suggeswtions of the ingredients of the recipe shall hover down the textfield are the user would type something. But I am having problem on how to target the element using its ID. The textfields are added dynamically on the page and here is my code:

```
      $('#button').click(function(){

            var id = $('.gc').length + 1;

            var n       = $('.num_of_fields').val(), // number of groups to add
                new_row = '<span class="gc group" id="'+id+'">'
                               +'<input type="text" name="ingr_name[]" id="input_' +id+'" onkeyup = "suggest(this.value)" onblur = "fill()" value="" autocomplete="off" />&nbsp;'
                               +'<?php echo form_input('amount[]', set_value('amount[]')); ?>&nbsp;'
                               +'<?php echo form_input('unit[]', set_value('unit[]')); ?>&nbsp;'
                               +'<span class="remove">Remove</span>'
                               +'<div class="suggestion_box" id="suggestions_' +id+'" style="display: none;">'
                                   +'<div class="suggestion_list" id="suggestion_list_' +id+'">&nbsp;</div>'
                               +'</div>'
                          +'</span>';

            for ( var i = 0; i < n ; i++ ) {

                $("#ingr").append(new_row);

            }   

            return false;

      });
```

Now, I could successfully add fields on the fly and I'm stuck on how to make the autosuggest work. I am trying with this code:

```
function suggest(input_string)
{
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    if(input_string.length == 0)
    {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
        //$('#input').addClass('load');
        $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>recipe/autosuggest", {query_string: ""+input_string+""}, function(data) {

            if(data.length > 0) 
            {
                $("#suggestions").fadeIn();
                $("#suggestion_list").html(data);
                //$("#input").removeClass('load');
            }   
        });
    }
}

function fill(this_value)
{
    $(".input").val(this_value);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 100);    
}
```

I have tried to see if my var id = $(this).attr('id'); would give the the ID of the input field but unfortunately, it doesn't give me what I need.

Is there a way for me to solve this? Your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

By the way, to be exact, I wanted to get the id of '' so that I could just simply do like:

```
("#suggestions_" +id).fadeIn();
("#suggestion_list_" +id).html(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your suggest function, it has no idea what `this` is. You can change your suggest function to be like the following:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.suggest = function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var input_string = $(this).val();
        ...
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and then call that function like this:

```
$(this).suggest()
```

instead of:

```
suggest(this.value)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Jon, thank you for your response. I tried it and it gave me the id of the input element. But I was wondering if how about, I wanted to get the id of the outermost span that wraps the whole row?

Comment: You could do `$(this).parent().attr('id');`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You do not get the id, because you are not passing the input to the function and `this` will be `window` inside your function.

Instead of relying on the `id`, give the inputs a class:

```
+'<input type="text" name="ingr_name[]" class="suggest-input" onblur="fill()"
     value="" autocomplete="off" />&nbsp';
```

Then in your `$(document).ready` bind a live event to that class and add the code of your suggest function:

```
$('.suggest-input').live('keyup' function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var myval = $this.val();
    var url   = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recipe/autosuggest";

    if(myval.length == 0) {
        $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $.post(, {query_string: myval},
            function(data) {
               if(data.length > 0) {
                    $("#suggestions").fadeIn();
                    $("#suggestion_list").html(data);
               }   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Majid, will this work even if I have multiple input boxes on the page?

Comment: Yes, `class` could be used on multiple elements. All elements with the `suggest-input` class will be selected and the live keyup will be bound to them, even dynamically added ones.

Comment: Will the suggestions be of individual textfield?

Comment: Do you mean each text field would send `its own` value? If so, yes, that's what would happen, but then when your ajax `post` completes, all boxes will fade in a *single* suggestions span or whatever it is, because here you are using an `id`. And by the way, for some reason I cannot edit my answer and there is an omission in the post line - it should read as: `$.post(url, {query_string: myval},` - the `url` is missing.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean! I will change the code so it would use the correct suggestion box.

Comment: Thanks Majid. I'm also trying to look for solutions.

Comment: After reviewing your `$('#button').click` function I find the design  too choppy to be corrected without changing your markup. You should move the markup that javascript is adding, to your html. But without seeing your html I cannot suggest anything more specific.